# How to setup dual boot (non windows) and switch later

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I wish to be able to dual boot into an OS (windows CE) and ubuntu, with the option to switch the default boot order later (by modifying a file on the FAT partition holding windows CE). Windows CE can boot from either DOS or EFI.
Ubuntu doesn't recognise the setup (unsurprising).
I'm a bit of noob for this stuff, and the docs for Grub etc aren't giving me any joy.

So, in summary, I want partitions: [FAT (DOS/windows CE, boot) | EXT4 (ubuntu) | Swap] and I want to be able to boot into the FAT(windows CE) as default, but be able to switch to boot into the ubuntu by modifying a config file on the Fat partition.

Thanks

Comment: Windows CE? Is this then one of those 32 bit UEFI systems with 64 bit processor, Which was designed just to make it difficult to install anything but Windows? What specific brand/model system. What cpu, RAM, video chip?

Comment: It's a generic x86 motherboard, nothing special

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found that I can install Grub4Dos http://sourceforge.net/projects/grub4dos/ I used bootlace.exe from DOS to setup Grub4Dos in the MBR, and created a menu.lst which boots into DOS (and then into windows CE). To swap to booting from linux, I then just need to modify the menu.lst file on the c: drive to make it boot into Linux on the second partition...

It seems like the documentation for grub4dos is pretty terrible, but http://diddy.boot-land.net/grub4dos/Grub4dos.htm helped a lot